# Error handling with UIAlertController

Tags: ios, swift, uialertcontroller

I have a `UIAlertController` with a textfield that allows users to type in a title to name a file before sending the data to the server.  However, the backend could reject the file for a couple reasons and an error needs to be displayed.  How can I display the error I get back from the server in the same alert controller where I entered the file name?

```
class FileController: UIViewController
{

    var alertController: UIAlertController?

    func savePressed()
    {
        createAlert()
    }

    func createAlert()
    {

        self.alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Save", message: "Name your file.", preferredStyle: .Alert)

        let saveAsPublicAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Make Public", style: .Default) { (_) in

        let fileTitle = self.alertController!.textFields![0] as UITextField

            if fileTitle.text != ""
            {
                self.initiateSave(fileTitle.text!, share: true)
            }
        }

        let saveAsPrivateAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Make Private", style: .Default) { (_) in

            let fileTitle = self.alertController!.textFields![0] as UITextField

            if fileTitle.text != ""
            {
                self.initiateSave(fileTitle.text!, share: false)
            }
        }


        let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .Cancel) { (_) in }

        self.alertController!.addTextFieldWithConfigurationHandler { (textField) in

            NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserverForName(UITextFieldTextDidChangeNotification, object: textField, queue: NSOperationQueue.mainQueue()) { (notification) in
            saveAsPrivateAction.enabled = textField.text != ""
            saveAsPublicAction.enabled = textField.text != ""
            }
        }

        self.alertController!.addAction(saveAsPublicAction)
        self.alertController!.addAction(saveAsPrivateAction)
        self.alertController!.addAction(cancelAction)

        self.presentViewController(self.alertController!, animated: true, completion: nil)


    }
}

func initiateSave(title:String?, share: Bool?)
{
     //package file
     initiatePost()

}

func initiatePost()
{
     //Send file data to server.  Receive any errors and handle
}
```

Answer (score 1):

On your server you can add more logic to send `JSON` data with that information.

For example:

```
{
    "success": true,
    "message": "Data received sucessfully"
}
```

If The request was successful, if not:

```
{
    "success": false,
    "message": "There is an error"
}
```

So when you parse that `JSON` you would check if `success` is false, and display the error message inside of the `message` key.

Comment: Thats what I'm doing.  I'm wondering how can I display the results in the same alert controller where I entered the file name.

Comment: @Brosef ok I see what you mean, For that you will need to call  `self.presentViewController`  again

Comment: So i receive the error in the `initiatePost` function and the alert controller is still present when the error is received.  How do I display the error in the alert controller?

Comment: @Brosef your function `createAlert()` should take the message as a parameter and that would solve your problem

Comment: so initially `createAlert()` gets called for the user to enter the file name.  Once the file name has been entered and the user hits save, `initiateSave()` gets called, which then calls `initiatePost()` so send the data to the server.  You're saying that `initiatePost()` should call `createAlert()` if an error is received?  The alert controller is already created and present - why do it all over again?

Comment: because pressing the button on alertcontroller would dismiss it automatically, the only other way I can think of , is if you disable the button and perform validation on the `UITextField` delegate instead